# Do you get moved down a section on a USCF chess tournament if your score is low?

Tags: tournament, uscf, tournament-directors

For example, I would like to play a class championship tournament. I'm a class B, but I registered for the Expert class section. If I don't score enough points to play anyone in my section for the rest of the tournament, will I get moved down the class A section?

Could someone explain what would happen?

Master
U2200 
U2000
U1800
U1600
U1400

etc.

Comment: There is no rule that you must score enough points to play anyone else in a tournament.

Comment: If you have the lowest score (and the lowest rating) and there are an odd number of players, you will get a bye for a round (you won't play anyone and you will automatically get a point). This can only happen to you once per tournament, though.

Comment: @dfan Will I still get to play an opponent in all six rounds of the tournament if everyone has a higher score than me on the Expert section? Perhaps get one bye, but still participate for five rounds?

Comment: You will get one bye at most, so you will still get at least five games. And even if you get a bye in one round, if other sections have a bye too it is possible that the tournament director will pair you with one of the other bye players as an extra rated game that isn't included in any of the sections.

Answer (score 5):

You do not get moved out of your bracket.  If you're a B-player in the Expert section, expect to finish at the bottom.  I'm not even sure if you're allowed to 'play up' unless you play in the open section.

Comment: In most USCF tournaments you are allowed to play up, although sometimes there are limits on how many sections up you can play.